# Asp core 2.2 Multiply authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

How can two `JWT` authentication schemes run simultaneously? In case one of them is invalid, then the whole request should be treated as unauthorized. Otherwise, all claims should be merged into the single `ClaimsIdentity`. I have the following configuration in the startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtBearerOptions)).Bind(opt);
                opt.Validate();
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("CustomBearer", opt =>
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("CustomJwtBearerOptions").Bind(opt);
            opt.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
            opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("CustomAuthorization", out StringValues headerValue))
                    {
                        ctx.Token = headerValue.ToString().Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            opt.Validate();
        });
```

If I run request and both tokens are valid then I get merged claims list (as expected). But if one token is `valid`, while another one is `invalid`, I still get `200 ok` (the only difference is that this time I get only half of the claims).
So how can I get 'unauthorized' if at least one token is invalid?

P.S. Please, don't judge hard, I'm a pretty newbie in that field. Thanks)

Comment: You can setup a Forward selector on the default scheme that forwards the authentication to your other scheme if some condition is true. You could decode the token and decide it should try the other based on some claim?

Comment: @juunas I can't. I need simply both tokens to be valid at the same time. And the only way to reach that is to validate them against auth handlers. So, forwarding, unfortunately , isn't an option here.

Comment: Okay, then how about kind of re-implementing AuthenticationMiddleware? So instead of having `app.UseAuthentication();` have your own middleware that first tries to call Authenticate on the first scheme, and if that doesn't work, the second scheme. Whichever succeeds, assign the principal to User on HttpContext.